# How to add 1 to a value in an input field with javascript on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a shopping cart and I want to implement an update quantities per item.. Let me show you that code maybe it will be easier to explain.

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-quantity-input">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="" value="<?php echo $items['qty']; ?>">
     <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-up"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
     <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
</div>
```

I want that when user click on the link add-one to increase the amount on the input field and when they click #decrease to reduce by one the amount on the input field just visually no AJAX or anything.

I don't know much of JavaScript that's why I seek your help.

Comment: Please next time show a minimal effort to answer your own question posting the code you had issues with!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $(".quantity-input-up").click(function(){
    var inpt = $(this).parents(".custom-quantity-input").find("[name=quantity]");
    var val = parseInt(inpt.val());
    if ( val < 0 ) inpt.val(val=0);
    inpt.val(val+1);
  });
  $(".quantity-input-down").click(function(){
    var inpt = $(this).parents(".custom-quantity-input").find("[name=quantity]");
    var val = parseInt(inpt.val());
    if ( val < 0 ) inpt.val(val=0);
    if ( val == 0 ) return;
    inpt.val(val-1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-quantity-input">
  <input type="number" min="0" name="quantity" class="" value="5">
     <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-up"><i class="fa fa-angle-up">+</i></a>
     <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down">-</i></a>
</div>

<div class="custom-quantity-input">
  <input type="number" min="0" name="quantity" class="" value="9">
     <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-up"><i class="fa fa-angle-up">+</i></a>
     <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down">-</i></a>
</div>

<div class="custom-quantity-input">
  <input type="number" min="0" name="quantity" class="" value="200">
     <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-up"><i class="fa fa-angle-up">+</i></a>
     <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down">-</i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try always to use `radix` in parseInt

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps:

```js
$( "#more" ).click(function() {
  var qtt = parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
  $('#quantity').val(qtt+1);
});

$( "#less" ).click(function() {
  var qtt = parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
  if (qtt > 0) { //does not allow negative values
    $('#quantity').val(qtt-1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="quantity" value="5">
<button id="more" type="button">+</button>
<button id="less" type="button">-</button>
```

Do not forget to include the jQuery project.

Comment: yep use ID and forget about using class and code reusability. OP already posted a quite good (beside `name=""`) HTML code.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, why you forget about `parseInt` radix here? :) My opinion - no matter what way(id, names, classes, or document.all iteration) used in answer. SO answers are never ready to production code.

Comment: @vp_arth - Radix added. Thanks.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan - The code is placed here is for explanation, not for production. And as the author said he had no great javascript knowledge I thought it was easier to understand so ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **nicer** and more **portable** solution that accounts for multiple inputs on a page:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".quantity-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                               // Don't scroll top.
    var $inp = $(this).closest("div").find("input"),  // Get input
        isUp = $(this).is(".quantity-input-up"),      // Is up clicked? (Boolean)
        currVal = parseInt($inp.val(), 10);           // Get curr val
    $inp.val(Math.max(0, currVal += isUp ? 1 : -1));  // Assign new val
  });

  // Other DOM ready code here
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="custom-quantity-input">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="" value="0">
  <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-up">&#9650;</a>
  <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-down">&#9660;</a>
</div>

<div class="custom-quantity-input">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" class="" value="2">
  <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-up">&#9650;</a>
  <a href="#" class="quantity-btn quantity-input-down">&#9660;</a>
</div>
```

the `event.preventDefault()` is just to make sure your browser does not scroll to top on anchor click.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way:

```js
function initCartCounter(input, upBtn, downBtn) {
  upBtn.onclick = () => input.value++;
  downBtn.onclick = () => input.value--;
}

//No matter which way you get these elements
initCartCounter(
  document.getElementById('val'),
  document.links[0],
  document.links[1]
);
```

```html
<input id="val" type="number" value="0"/>
<a href="javascript:;">Add</a>
<a href="javascript:;" >Sub</a>
```

A bit cleaner and scalable:

```js
!function() {
document.querySelectorAll('.cart')
.forEach(cart => {
  let input = cart.querySelector('.cart-number');
  cart.querySelector('.cart-number-inc')
    .addEventListener('click', () => input.innerText = (input.innerText|0)+1);
  cart.querySelector('.cart-number-dec')
    .addEventListener('click', () => input.innerText = (input.innerText|0)-1);
})  
}();
```

```css
.pointer {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="cart">
  <span class="cart-number">0</span>
  <span class="cart-number-inc pointer">Add</span>
  <span class="cart-number-dec pointer">Dec</span>
</div>
```

---

Best way, imo, is to use native `input[type=number]`:

```html
<input type="number" value="0"/>
```

Comment: Great, how is this implemented if I have multiple inputs with different ID?

Comment: Roko, wrong answer! ID is only if you 100% percent sure that it will not be replicated in the same page.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the reason that your answer is wrong, even when you show a solution with classes, is because you changed the OP whole design. You cant solve a problem by completely changing a code, because it might be a part of a bigger system with a well written design. In this case you have to find a workaround. Plus, he didn't ask for a design help, but to push him forward a bit.